# Calculate difference between multiple timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sum, window-functions

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=432edfaca7f3ae6d675aeeef0d1be39f)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    time_stamp DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    sales_quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO sales
(time_stamp, product, sales_quantity
)
VALUES 
("2020-01-14", "Product_A", "100"),
("2020-01-14", "Product_B", "300"),
("2020-01-14", "Product_C", "600"),

("2020-01-15", "Product_A", "100"),
("2020-01-15", "Product_B", "350"),
("2020-01-15", "Product_C", "600"),

("2020-01-16", "Product_A", "130"),
("2020-01-16", "Product_B", "350"),
("2020-01-16", "Product_C", "670"),
("2020-01-16", "Product_D", "400"),

("2020-01-17", "Product_A", "130"),
("2020-01-17", "Product_B", "350"),
("2020-01-17", "Product_C", "700"),
("2020-01-17", "Product_D", "450");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
time_stamp          difference
2020-01-14             0   
2020-01-15            50   = (100+350+600) - (100+300+600)
2020-01-16           500   = (130+350+670+400) - (100+350+600)
2020-01-17            80   = (130+350+700+450) - (130+350+670+400)
```

---

In the above result I want to calculate the `difference` of the `sales_quantiy` between multiple `timestamps`.

I tried to go with this query:

```
SELECT
time_stamp,
(SUM(t1.time_stamp_01) - SUM(t1.time_stamp_02)) AS difference
FROM
  (SELECT 
  time_stamp,
  SUM(CASE WHEN time_stamp  = '2020-01-14' THEN sales_quantity ELSE 0 END) AS time_stamp_01,
  SUM(CASE WHEN time_stamp  = '2020-01-15' THEN sales_quantity ELSE 0 END) AS time_stamp_02
  FROM sales
  GROUP BY 1) t1
GROUP BY 1;
```

However, it somehow does not calcualte the `difference` between the `timestamps` and it is also limited to two `timestamps`.

How do I need to modify the `query` to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use aggregation and `lag()`:

```
select time_stamp, 
    sum(sales_quantity) 
        - lag(sum(sales_quantity), 1, sum(sales_quantity)) over(order by time_stamp) diff
from sales
group by time_stamp
order by time_stamp
```

This works in MySQL 8.0, but not in MariaDB 10.3 (which is what your fiddle uses). You can use:

```
select time_stamp, sum_sales_quantity - coalesce(lag(sum_sales_quantity) over(order by time_stamp), sum_sales_quantity) diff
from (
    select time_stamp, sum(sales_quantity) sum_sales_quantity
    from sales
    group by time_stamp
) t
order by time_stamp
```